# При загрузке модуля react выдает такую ошибку: Class constructor RegisterForm cannot be invoked without 'new'. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Основная структура модуля:

```
class RegisterForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const success = false;
      return ( ...
       {!success ? ( ... ) : ( ... )}
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поменял class на const и стрелочную функцию сделал + убрал рендер

Comment: ну такое. а если нужен классовый компонент?